# Angular 8 and jQuery: want to call a function

Tags: jquery, angular

I want to call a function clicking on dynamically generated URLs.

```
var push_div = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunc('1')">Hello1</a></div>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunc('2')">Hello2</a></div>';

myFunc(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

But I received an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined

Then I modified my code as like:

```
var push_div = '<a id="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Hello1</a></div>' + '<a id="2" href="javascript:void(0)">Hello2</a></div>';


$(document).on('click', $(push_div).find('a').eq(0), function() {
  // my code
});
```

This is not console me any error however, I cannot detect which hyperlink I clicked. Any idea?

Comment: 1. Mixing jQuery and Angular is an anti-pattern. 2 Why not wrap the url in a div and then proceed?

Comment: @NicholasK Please give an idea in your answer.

Comment: Try to append "push_div" to some container div in your page. push_div is just an variable now. You need to append it to the DOM and then you can access the $(push_div) and bind click events to the anchor tags

Comment: Added an answer, let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the id property of the link which is clicked and call functions based on the different id. Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcze41)

here is the quick explanation,

All you need to do is,

Prepare HTML data inside your component file.

```
var push_div =
      '<a id="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Hello1</a></div>' +
      '<a id="2" href="javascript:void(0)">Hello2</a></div>';
```

Grab a reference of a div in which you want to append this HTML data.

```
const div = document.getElementById("wrapper");
$(div).html(push_div);
```

add the click event listener on the newly created anchor tags,

```
$(div).find('a').on("click", ev => {
      switch (ev.target.id) {
        case "1":
          this.myFunction1();
          break;
        case "2":
          this.myFunction2();
          break;
      }
    });
```

That's it. By the way, you may want to do this inside your angular app but actually this logic has nothing to do with an angular app. this is a pure javascript thing. I hope this will help.

Here I would like to share the whole component file.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name = "Angular";

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const div = document.getElementById("wrapper");

    var push_div =
      '<a id="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Hello1</a></div>' +
      '<a id="2" href="javascript:void(0)">Hello2</a></div>';

    $(div).html(push_div);

    $(div).find('a').on("click", ev => {
      switch (ev.target.id) {
        case "1":
          this.myFunction1();
          break;
        case "2":
          this.myFunction2();
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  myFunction1() {
    alert(1);
  }

  myFunction2() {
    alert(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for it?

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara it's already there in the answer in the first line.